# Oracle Update last entry column with specific values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to Update a row in a table at Oracle Apex platform, and more specifically to get the present_indication value from the last entry with the same serial_number and put it as previous_indication in the new row.
My table HYDRO_COUNTS is something like this:

```
OID,SERIAL_NUMBER,PROV_NUMBER,HDRCNTS_PREVIOUS_IND,HDRCNTS_PRESENT_IND
```

So far I have tried a lot of queries about getting the last entered value with the same SERIAL_NUMBER and PROV_NUMBER but nothing worked. Here is my Update query.

```
UPDATE HYDRO_COUNTS
SET HDRCNTS_PREVIOUS_IND = (SELECT HDRCNTS_PRESENT_IND FROM HYDRO_COUNTS WHERE PROV_NUMBER = 
:P20_PROV_NUMBER AND SERIAL_NUMBER = :P20_SERIAL_NUMBER )
WHERE OID = :P20_OID ;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: For example lets say that I run a test on a date and insert the indication of a machine to my table and after some time i run the test on the same machine again, so i want to be able to view the last indication, in order to compare it with the new indication.

Answer (score 0):

If `OID` is a unique column that always increments you can do something like

```
UPDATE HYDRO_COUNTS
  SET HDRCNTS_PREVIOUS_IND = (SELECT HDRCNTS_PRESENT_IND
                                FROM HYDRO_COUNTS
                                WHERE PROV_NUMBER = :P20_PROV_NUMBER AND
                                      SERIAL_NUMBER = :P20_SERIAL_NUMBER AND
                                      OID = (SELECT MAX(OID)
                                               FROM HYDRO_COUNTS
                                               WHERE PROV_NUMBER = :P20_PROV_NUMBER AND
                                                     SERIAL_NUMBER = :P20_SERIAL_NUMBER AND
                                                     OID < :P20_OID)
  WHERE OID = :P20_OID
```

Comment: The OID is indeed produced via a increment sequence! As i read your answer it seems right to me, both the syntax and the logic, but for some unkown reason it keeps doing nothing for me ..

Comment: Your code is correct Bob, I made a mistake in Apex, so that was why it didn't work. Thanks a lot for your help mate!